# Cells in Dynamic Table not showing when running app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dynamic-tables

I've added both an image and a label to my dynamic table. They do display when using a static table but not a dynamic table. Am I doing something wrong? I'm fairly new to Xcode so if anyone could give me some tips that would be great.

Images for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnIRT.jpg

Comment: What is a dynamic table? The one you add programatically (not with storyboard)? If so you need to register a class or nib file using the `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or  `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`

Comment: Sorry if a confused you, but under the 'Content' drop-down I'm using Dynamic Prototypes. If I choose Static Cells the data appears from the cells but not with Dynamic Prototypes. Image: http://imgur.com/FRv3v9Z

Comment: I see.  You should: 1. Set the datasource and delegate of the table view to your viewcontroller. 2. In your view controller implement `numberOfItemsInSection` and `cellFoRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Dynamic tables use, well... Dynamic data. You set the `dataSource` to an object (usually your view controller) and implement the `tableView:numberOfRowsAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Of course, your object needs to conform to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol. If your table view uses custom cells, your cells need to have a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`. Also, every cell prototype needs to have a reuse identifier set, which you use to instantiate a cell using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:atIndexPath:`. Look for some tutorial on YouTube about `UITableView`.

Comment: Thank you both Ross and Alejandro. I see where you are going, but I have no idea of how to set the delegate and how to structure both `numberOfItemsInSection` and `cellFoRowAtIndexPath`. I'm writing in Swift, could someone show me how I could do this?

Comment: Look ah this tutorial I found, should make things more clear to you: http://www.codingexplorer.com/getting-started-uitableview-swift/